# pick image from gallery and apply effects factory effects

Tags: android

I am following effects factory tutorial from this blog post :http://grishma102.blogspot.in/2013/10/apply-effects-on-image-using-effects.html
In the above post drawable is static and is picked from drawable resource, I want to pick resource from the device gallery and apply effects on it, what changes do I have to make in the above blog post code to achieve so.

Answer (score 0):

Create an Intent to pick image from gallery like this

Create a global variable

`private int OPEN_GALLERY = 101`

Call the below intent on click of a button or something.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(
                                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                                intent.setType("image/*");
                                startActivityForResult(
                                        Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),
                                        OPEN_GALLERY);
```

Get the selected image using `onActivityResult()`

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {


        case OPEN_GALLERY:
            if (data != null) {


                try {
                    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                    String[] filePath = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                    Cursor c = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(
                            selectedImage, filePath, null, null, null);
                    c.moveToFirst();
                    int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
                    String picturePath = c.getString(columnIndex);
                    c.close();

                    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath,options);

                    //Pass bitmap to loadtextures method
                    loadTextures(bm);


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;

            }
    }
}
```

Pass bitmap to the `loadTextures()` method like this

```
private void loadTextures(Bitmap bm) {  
 // Generate textures  
 GLES20.glGenTextures(2, mTextures, 0);  
 // Load input bitmap  
 Bitmap bitmap = bm;  
 mImageWidth = bitmap.getWidth();  
 mImageHeight = bitmap.getHeight();  
 mTexRenderer.updateTextureSize(mImageWidth, mImageHeight);  
 // Upload to texture  
 GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextures[0]);  
 GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);  
 // Set texture parameters  
 GLToolbox.initTexParams();  
 }
```

Comment: I was able to get bitmap from gallery, but after that was not able to set bitmap to the blog post code.

Comment: sorry I didn't notice that you're using GLSurfaceView. Edited my answer. Please check it. Call the `loadTextures(bm)` in `onActivityResult()` method.

Comment: I did but it won't render the bitmap.

Comment: it gives error call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)

Comment: I'm not sure how I can help you with that, as I have not much knowledge on OpenGL.